plt.savefig saves empty figure
For some probably stupid reason, the figure is kept blank.
plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))

Bar_Target_Gen = ax.bar(0, Target_Gen, color='#00BA00', label='Target Gen.', width=0.5)

Bar_Gen_Energy = ax.bar(0, Gen_Energy, color='#DBFF1F', label='Gen. Energy', width=0.4)

Bar_E_Loss = ax.bar(0, E_Loss, color='#A9B3A9', label='E. Loss', bottom=Gen_Energy, width=0.4)

Bar_Theor_Energy = ax.bar(0, Theor_Energy, color=(0, 0, 0, 0), edgecolor='black', linestyle='dotted', width=0.5, linewidth=1.5, label='Theor. Energy', )

ax.text(0, Target_Gen, '%d' % Target_Gen + ' MWh', ha='center', va='top', fontsize=20, color='#FFFFFF', fontweight='semibold')
ax.text(0, 30, '%d' % Gen_Energy + ' MWh', ha='center', va='top', fontsize=20, color='#FFFFFF', fontweight='semibold')
ax.text(0, Theor_Energy, '%d' % Theor_Energy + ' MWh', ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=16, color='Black', fontweight='semibold')

ax.set_xticks([])   

ax.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.33, 1))

fig=plt.figure()
fig.savefig('input/grafico.jpg', dpi=100)
plt.show()

I've tried everything, but only one blank figure is saved. Any capeless heroes who can help me?

Make a [mcve].  What is ax?  Add your imports.

Remove the line fig=plt.figure() at the end of your script. you are initialising and empty figure there which then gets saved to disk.

Also need to call the original figure fig if you want to use fig.savefig.
